# What is the maximum number of screens that android can use at once?

Tags: android, touchscreen

Today I heard that android can only support two separate touchscreens at any time.

Is this strictly true? I haven;t been able to find a reference online.

If limited to two screens only, the project I work on gets a lot more complex as we have three screens on our product.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, while making an application, you are not restricted to create as many screens, or technically called Fragments and divide the screen into small portions. Ofcourse, the more the fragments, the greater the latency for the android system to process various interactive events that will be generated by the end user. Also, multiple ViewGroups present inside these various fragment layouts, will increase the complexity of the application, hence adding to the latency.